# Creating Libraries using Swift

Tags: swift, shared-libraries

I need to create many Swift projects in the same workspace, each project using code from a shared library. This shared library would have classes that would be inherited from in the projects.

1) How can I create a library that all projects can use?

2) How do I specify in each project that they should reference the shared library?

Comment: Follow this tutorial -> http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

Solution...

Ok, I never had an issue creating a Framework but I was not able to add it to the projects.

The solution, you need to build the Framework against the Generic IOS device or a connected iPhone. Building it against one of the simulator devices initially is not the way to go.

Once it has been built against Generic IOS device once, you can add the framework to the project.